# Is it possible to move the LAMP server to another drive on the same computer?

Tags: server, partitioning, xubuntu, lamp, drive

I want to move the `/var/www/` folder to a different partition drive and start the server from there, how can I do that?

Comment: What is a "parted drive"?

Comment: @KarlRichter I guess a different partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to edit the configuration for apache. The default configuration is stored in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`.

Edit this file with (`sudo -H gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default` for example) and locate the line

`DocumentRoot /var/www`

and change the path to your new path. Afterwards, you can reload the apache configuration with

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

If you are serving over SSL you'll need to edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl` as well.

Comment: /etc/apache2/sites-available/default: No such file or directory

Comment: Are there any other files in that directory, or does it not exist? You could search the right config file using `grep -r DocumentRoot /etc/apache2`

Comment: I found the files in that directory but know the standard permissions are gone. When I go to http://localhost/ it says 403 forbidden.

Comment: Nevermind, switched everything back. DocumentRoot can't see my hard drive lol

Comment: You need to make sure that whatever directory you change your DocumentRoot to, that Apache has +x permissions on it and all its parent directories and that the files in your DocumentRoot have +r. E.g. if your www dir is /path/to/dir and you have an index.html in there, /path, /path/to, /path/to/dir would all need o+x or g+x and belong to the same group as apache and that /path/to/dir/index.html has o+r or g+r. This is required so Apache can list the files in the directory and read them.

Comment: @hordur: +1 just for understanding the question!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

Move the content of `/var/www` to the new partition and mount this partition with an entry in `fstab` at `/var/www`.

On Ask Ubuntu there are many answers for the correct entry in the `fstab`.

Comment: That doesn't work.. I have moved the files to another partition know but I want that Apache is using the second partition, not the first where /var/www/html already exist. When I restart the server and go to http://localhost/ the folder is empty because apache doesnt know where the files are in the parted drive

Comment: You have forgotten to mount the partition.